# Java does not know when file does NOT exist

Tags: java, file, exists

Java knows when a file exists as it prints out "File found" but when the file does not exists it does NOT print "File not found"

```
    File file = new File(filePath, "Test_1.exe");

    if (file.exists()){
        System.out.println("File found");
    }else{
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
```

does any one know why? the file path is correct as I have double checked this. Just weird that if the file does not exists it wont print out but will if it does.

I have also tried if (!file.exists()) with not luck!

Comment: it sure seems to print `"File not found"` for me if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Try checking with `File#canRead()` if your application even has the rights to read it, could be that too.

Comment: perhaps there's an error that you're trapping and ignoring?

Comment: 'The file path is correct as I have double checked this'. Check again. Obviously it is not correct.

Comment: Agree with EJP, maybe an error is thrown at the first line.

Comment: @gigadot - *"maybe an error is thrown at the first line"*.  AFAIK, that can't happen ... unless the error is OOME or StackOverflowError or something equally catastrophic.

Comment: what does file.getAbsolutePath() return?

Comment: @gigadot: I didn't say anything about throwing errors at the first line. Your comment is nonsense. What I said was that his path is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @EJP I did not mean that you meant an error was thrown. I thought that if the path were incorrect, the constructor would throw an exception then you wouldn't get to the if statement.  However, @Stephen C has enlighten me that this is impossible. File constructor does absolutely no checking so my statement does really make no sense. Apologies. Do I still misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
try
{
    File file = new File(filePath, "Test_1.exe");

     if (file.exists())
     {
          System.out.println("File found");
     }
     else
     {
            System.out.println("File not found");
      }
}
catch(SecurityException se)
{
     se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path to the file. eg :

```
File file = new File(filePath, "c:/temp/Test_1.exe");
```

From the javadocs :

> A relative pathname, in contrast, must be interpreted in terms of information taken from some other pathname. By default the classes in the java.io package always resolve relative pathnames against the current user directory. This directory is named by the system property user.dir, and is typically the directory in which the Java virtual machine was invoked.